# Invalid date notation: nil! Adyen Rails Gem Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, payment

I'm looking to integrate my rails application with the payment provider Adyen, I've installed the Adyen Gem and put the code in to make a basic form, but I'm getting an error:

Adyen Gem: http://github.com/wvanbergen/adyen

> Invalid date notation: nil!
>
> /Users/chris/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/adyen-0.1.5/lib/adyen/formatter.rb:10:in
>   `fmt_date'
>   /Users/chris/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/adyen-0.1.5/lib/adyen/form.rb:35:in`
>   do_attribute_transformations!'
>   /Users/chris/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/adyen-0.1.5/lib/adyen/form.rb:40:in
>   `payment_fields'
>   /Users/chris/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/adyen-0.1.5/lib/adyen/form.rb:59:in`
>   hidden_fields'
>   app/views/payments/free.html.erb:7

my Code is:

```
 <% form_tag(:url => Adyen::Form.url) do %>
<%= Adyen::Form.hidden_fields(:merchant_account => 'myaccount',:skin_code => 'myperfectskin', :shared_secret => 'youllneverguess', :payment_amount => '1000') %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the Adyen's source, you'll see on [lib/adyen/form.rb](http://github.com/wvanbergen/adyen/blob/adyen-0.1.5/lib/adyen/form.rb) at the line 35 that there's a `ship_before_date` required option which you don't fill.

But you're using Adyen at it's version 0.1.5 when there's the 0.2.1 version (and apparently that "bug" has been corrected).
If you installed that version (with `gem install adyen -v=0.2.1`), you would be using a much more recent and reliable version of the library.

Comment: Thanks, worked perfect after filling in the ship_before_date (that bug still seemed to be there even with 0.2.1 though, oh well working now and that's what counts)